# JVM dying with no error, no OOM in kern.log

Tags: linux, java

My JVM sometimes, but not always, dies on startup with no error in any application or system log file.

There is nothing in `/var/log/kern.log`, nothing relevant in `dmesg`.

The thing is, even when I use `-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp` with the `suspend=y` option, which suspends the JVM waiting for a debugger to connect, before it runs the main method, the issue still happens sometimes, so I know it's not a bug in my Java code.

I know the application lasts for just over 5 seconds, because my JVM start script sleeps for 5 seconds and then checks that the PID of the JVM still exists, and it does. But when I then try to ssh in and check if the process still exists, it has vanished.

There is no log file or core dump in the working directory of the process (which is /home/blahblah).

Comment: Have you ruled out somebody doing a #kill -9 pid ?

Comment: Yes, no-one else is using this Linux VM, and I have spoken to the sysadmins, they would have mentioned if they had done that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing I didn't mention in the question, because I didn't think it was relevant, is that I was running the application's start script using another script which ssh's into the server, on my local machine.

I had recently added `-t` after `ssh` in this script - for another purpose (viewing log files using `less` on the server) - which was not needed for the start/stop script.

After removing this `-t` option for the start/stop case, this problem stopped happening.

A clue, that I should have paid attention to, is that the application died after *exactly* 5 seconds, which was the *same length of time* that the start script was sleeping for to check if the application was still alive after being started.